# What does the >?= operator mean?

Tags: c++, g++, operators

Looking through this C++ BigInt library and found the [BigInt.cpp](http://shygypsy.com/tools/BigInt.cpp) file. At the top there is a a comment at the top about compatibility:

> This class was written for the g++ compiler and uses some of the g++ extensions (like "long double" and the ">?=" operator).

What does that `>?=` operator do? I can't find a reference to it anywhere else.

Comment: long double is not a g++ extension...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's a GCC extension that was removed in GCC version 4.2 and later.

The equivalent of `a >?= b` is `a = max(a,b);`

There is also a very similar operator `a <?= b` which means the same as `a = min(a, b);`.

Answer (score 14):

[This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_6.html#SEC116) describes that `>?` is the 'maximum' operator, which returns the largest of its two numeric arguments. I'm guessing that the `>?=` combines this with assignment, presumably by assigning to the left-hand operand if the right-hand value is larger.

Comment: tim, sounds plausable - and very likely, therefore, +1 :)

Comment: It kinda makes sense that they'd use `>?` for the maximum operator, seeing that the maximum can be computed in regular C++ like this: `max = lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs`.

Comment: Compiler specific language extensions?! I thought only MS were dumb enough to do that. Boo! Hiss!

Comment: I went to test it, but as reported elsewhere it's been removed in more recent versions of g++.

Comment: @David: There's also `__attribute__`.  But of course some extensions are more obnoxious than others.

Comment: As long as there's a compiler switch to compile in a fully standards-compliant mode, I'm happy. Bonus points if standards-compliant is the default.

Comment: `>?=` is really quite disgusting though!

Comment: Out of interest, were you able to overload these operators?

Answer (score 3):

See [C extension: <? and >? operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437410/c-extension-and-operators)

It's the max-then-assign operator: Take the greater of the left and right sides and stuff it back into the lefthand side.

It's removed from g++ and should be replaced with `max` (or `min` for `<?=`)