# What is the <?= operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the >?= operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

I was wondering what is the `<?=` operator I keep seeing in C++ code. It doesn't compile on my system, but I'm sure it is correct. It's used like this:`a <?= something;`

Also, what would I need to do to be able to compile it?

EDIT POST:

Please see this source code (it is a solution of the problem Square Fields (Problem B) of the winner of a practice [Google Code Jam](http://code.google.com/codejam/) contest -- see [here](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=32004#vf=1)). I saw the same pattern of characters in some other submissions too.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<map>
#include<numeric>
#include<cmath> using namespace std;

#define ALL(t) t.begin(),t.end()
#define FOR(i,n) for (int i=0; i<(int)(n); i++)
#define FOREACH(i,t) for (typeof(t.begin()) i=t.begin(); i!=t.end(); i++) typedef vector<int> vi; typedef long long int64;

int t[15][1<<15]; int main() {   int N;cin>>N;   for(int c=1;c<=N;c++){
    int n,k,x[30],y[30];
    cin>>n>>k;
    FOR(i,n)cin>>x[i]>>y[i];
    FOR(take,1<<n)if(take){
      int minx=1000000,maxx=-1,miny=1000000,maxy=-1;
      FOR(i,n)if(take&1<<i)minx<?=x[i],maxx>?=x[i],miny<?=y[i],maxy>?=y[i];
      t[1][take]=(maxx-minx)>?(maxy-miny); //      cout<<take<<" "<<t[1][take]<<endl;
    }
    for(int kk=2;kk<=k;kk++)FOR(take,1<<n){
      t[kk][take]=t[kk-1][take];
      for(int take2=take;take2;take2=(take2-1)&take)
        t[kk][take]<?=t[kk-1][take-take2]>?t[1][take2];
    }
    cout<<"Case #"<<c<<": "<<t[k][(1<<n)-1]<<endl;   }   return 0; }
```

Comment: You are mistaken, there is no such operator. Perhaps you saw something similar and got the order mixed up.

Comment: Maybe the code could be garbled due to code page issue. No such operator in C++.

Comment: It has to be a typo, and can't possibly compile on a reasonably-conforming C++ compiler. It's not [a trigraph nor a digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), and I have **never** seen a `<?=` in C++ code ever in the years I've done C++ programming. Can you provide more context? (Like say, a code snippet you found that has this?) It's possible that the code you're looking at isn't actually C++ at all.

Comment: `It doesn't compile on my system, but I'm sure it is correct.` Isn't the fact that it doesn't compile clue enough that it *isn't* correct? Learn to trust your compiler - it's going to be right about these things more often than you... :)

Comment: Just found out it's [an extension present in older versions of the GCC C++ compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean), which is probably why I've never seen such an operator. Closed as a duplicate.

Comment: No, Mac, sorry but not compiling on one system does not necessarily mean it is not correct. There are different compilers around with a bit different features.

Comment: @Grega: although it *may* compile under some circumstances, that doesn't necessarily make it correct. The standards are the way by which the behaviour of compilers are judged to be correct, and this is not a standards-compliant feature. That said, I do accept that the practical definition of "correct" is a bit broader than just "standards-compliant", and in that respect I can't say I entirely disagree with you. Whatever the case though, it's to be avoided since it's not portable.

Comment: @Mac: you are right, the use of word "correct" in my case is questionable in this case, but since this was used by a top contestant in Google Code Jam and his submission was not disqualified, I took it that it must be "correct" (in a way that it did compile on his system). Thanks again for helping out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

Its an extension in older versions of GCC. See this :

[What does the >?= operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

But then the extensions are  `<?`  and  `>?` . I still don't see `<?=`.

[6.1 Minimum and Maximum Operators in C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_6.html#SEC116)

---

EARLIER POST:

I assure you, there is no such operator in C++. Its certainly a mistyping.

The programmer most likely wanted to type either `<=` or `?:`

Or maybe you mistyped it here when in fact you intended to type a [digraph or trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) (but what you've typed is neither *digraph* nor *trigraph*).

As you yourself said `it doesn't compile on my system`. How would it? Its a typo.

Comment: It appears that `a <?= b` means `a = min(a, b)`, i.e. it's the assignment form of the `<?` operator.

Comment: @hammar: but `a<?b` returns minimum, anyway. So assignment in `<?=` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `<?` is to `<?=` just as `+` is to `+=`. So it not only computes the minimum but also assigns the result to `a`.

Comment: @hammar: ohh... makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say it was a trigraph operator, but it isn't even that. It's probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are getting mixed up with this operator: a ? b : c.
Otherwise, please post a link to some of the code that you've seen it in, because it sure ain't normal c++.
It could be another language, but googling it returns literally *nothing*, so I don't think that's the answer.

Comment: I posted an example code, but since my question was already answered.