# How to make '<?=' available for use in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the >?= operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

I found this code segment

```
...
for(k=i+1;k<j;k++) r <?= go(i,k,b)+go(k,j,b);
for(k='A';k<='Z';k++) r <?= 1+go(i,j,k);
...
```

I'm interested in `<?=` operator. It seems to me that it should compare value of `r` with right side of the operator and in case that right side is greater than `r` it should assign right side to `r`. I would like to know where are this (and similar operators, I suppose) defined and what should I do make them available for use with g++ compiler?

Comment: It's a pity that this doesn't have a standard operator. I use this type of assignment so often that I tend to include it as a member function `numclass::push_downto(const numclass &)` in number-like classes, but that's not really good style and you can't do it at all for plain primitive types.

Comment: It was the minimum assginment operator, the value was assigned if the right side was smaller

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<?=` operator was a GCC extension that was removed in version 4.2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean).

Use `std::min` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a valid C++ operator

Comment: Not standard, but an extension.

Comment: @Tomalak: ... so it's not a valid *standard* C++ operator. This doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid C++ operator. If the answer correctly specified standard vs extension, it would be correct. And, for what it's worth, I did not downvote it.

Comment: Extensions are called extensions because they extend the language. They are not the language.

Answer (score 0):

Not doable.   The operators that C++ supports are fixed, you can't add new ones.

Comment: Implementation extensions can.

Comment: GCC is *NOT* C++. The standard doesn't define such an operator.

Comment: "C++" can be read as "standard C++" or "practical C++". Without the qualifier, it's ambiguous.