# Where can I find more information on the C/++ operators <?= and >?=

Tags: c++, c, operators, expression, ternary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the >?= operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

I was reading some C++ code and I saw the operators `<?=` and `>?=`. From their usage it appears that `a <?= b` is equivalent to `a = (b < a) ? b : a` and `a >?= b` is `a = (b > a) ? b : a`. Are these distinct operators or just hacky uses of ternary expressions? If they're operators, why have I never seen them before in any C/++ references?

Comment: Do you have a link to the code you saw?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean