# <?= what does this mean in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the >?= operator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean)

I have encountered this line,

```
bot <?= fnet[v][u] ? fnet[v][u] : ( cap[u][v] - fnet[u][v] );
```

what does this `<?=`sign mean? Visual Studio 2012 says that it doesnt exist, then what is it? Maybe it was in some previous versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio is right, the operator is no longer valid. I'm not sure if it ever was, or it was a language extension. EDIT: It was a gcc extension that was removed - http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2005-09/msg00299.html

It's a conditional assignment - `a <?= b` means "assign `b` to `a` if `a < b`."

You can use `std::min` and `std::max` instead.

```
bot <?= fnet[v][u] ? fnet[v][u] : ( cap[u][v] - fnet[u][v] );
```

would translate to

```
bot = std::min(bot, fnet[v][u] ? fnet[v][u] : (cap[u][v]-fnet[u][v]) );
```

Comment: Thanks, so bot <?= fnet[v][u] ? fnet[v][u] : ( cap[u][v] - fnet[u][v] );  means that: if ( bot < fnet[v][u]) then fnet[v][u] = bot else bot = cap[u][v] - fnet[u][v] ?