# meaning of <?= and >? operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

What is the meaning of ? operators in the code below? where it is used?

```
adj[i][j] <?= adj[i][k] >? adj[k][j]
```

I coulidn't find this operator anywhere else

Comment: Try PHP - Not valid C++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're old, non-standard [compiler extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Min-and-Max.html) provided by G++ for computing the minimum or maximum of their operands.  `a <? b` is equivalent to `min(a, b)` (where each operator is computed only once, as in a call to an inline function), while `a >? b` is equivalent to `max(a, b)`.

The `<?=` and `>?=` forms are assignment forms of the operators—`a <?=b` is equivalent to `a = a <? b` etc.

In addition to being non-standard, these operators have been deprecated and removed from modern versions of G++.  From the [deprecated features](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html#Deprecated-Features) page:

> The G++ minimum and maximum operators (‘`<?`’ and ‘`>?`’) and their compound forms (‘`<?=`’) and ‘`>?=`’) have been deprecated and are now removed from G++. Code using these operators should be modified to use `std::min` and `std::max` instead.